# How to show a block, then hide it on body click in JQ

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an info bubble on a page. Users can open it by clicking on an  icon, and I want them to be able to close it by clicking anywhere in the body.

http://jsfiddle.net/etDBE/7/

I can't figure out how to trigger an open event, since the parent is always closing the bubble. I tried `$('body').not('.i-icon')` but that's not right. Any suggestions?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var iIsOpen = false;

    $('body').not('.i-icon').click(function () {
        if (iIsOpen == true) {
            //alert('close bubble');
            $('.i-narrow').hide();
            iIsOpen = false;
        }
    });


    $('.i-icon').click(function () {
        //alert('open bubble');
        $('.i-narrow').show();
        iIsOpen = true;
    });
});
```

Comment: Your fiddle doesnt work.

Comment: @EkoostikMartin That's the point of the question, he doesn't understand why it doesn't work...

Comment: @Nunners - it doesn't show the `div` either

Comment: @EkoostikMartin Because as his code stands, it will show the div and then instantly hide the div. Which is why the code doesn't work, but the OP didn't realise this.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work - I just showed what i tried. One of the answers below resolved it, i needed event.stopPropagation().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can shorten your code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click',function (e) {
        $('.i-narrow').hide();
    });
    $('.i-icon').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('.i-narrow').show();
    });
});
```

So basically, when you click any where in the document, then your `.i-narrow` will be hide

However if you click on the `.i-narrow` itself, the `click` event will be bubble up on the DOM tree which will trigger the `click` event at the `document` level as well and results in your `.i-narrow` will be hide again.

So that's the reason why you need to use **[e.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)** here to prevent your click event bubble up.

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/etDBE/12/)**

Answer (score 2):

Use [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) when you handle the click event of the open icon.

It will stop the click event bubbling up the DOM tree to the `Body` which is why the element was hiding.

Note that this will also mean that clicking the `i-icon` element whilst the "bubble" is shown will not hide the element as it will not trigger the Body's click event.

Code :

```
$('.i-icon').click(function () {
    event.stopPropagation(); // Stops the Click event bubbling up the DOM tree
    $('.i-narrow').show();
    iIsOpen = true;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you have many ways to do the same thing, this is another way for you verify:

```
$('.i-icon').click(function (e) {
    alert('open bubble');
    $('.i-narrow').show();
    iIsOpen = true;
    return false;
});
```

Just put `return false;` in the end of event.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var iIsOpen = false;

    $('body').bind('click',function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        if(!$(e.target).closest('.i-icon').length){
        if (iIsOpen == true) {
            //alert('close bubble');
            $('.i-narrow').hide();
            iIsOpen = false;
        }
        }
    });


    $('.i-icon').click(function () {
        //alert('open bubble');
        $('.i-narrow').show();
        iIsOpen = true;
    });

});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/etDBE/16/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<img class="i-icon" src="images/i.png">
<div class="i-narrow">
    <div>Content</div>
</div>
    </div>
```

**javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var iIsOpen = false;

    $(document).bind('click', function(e){ 
        var $clicked = $(e.target); 
        if (!($clicked.is('.container') || $clicked.parents().is('.container'))) { 
            $('.i-narrow').hide();
        } else { 
            // click inside, to what you want, or nothing :) 
        } 
    });


    $('.i-icon').click(function () {
        //alert('open bubble');
        $('.i-narrow').show();
        iIsOpen = true;
    });
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/etDBE/23/) for this